# What are good packages / techniques for writing more readable LaTeX *code*?

Tags: packages, sourcecode, big-list

A while ago I stumbled upon the [`semantic`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/semantic) package --- its 'math ligatures' feature in particular --- and the whole way in which I write math-code in LaTeX changed.

Instead of

```
\[
  \sem{\sigma}_s^x \quad \defeq \quad
    \setbuild
      { \sigma' \subseteq \Sigma }
      { \exists s' \in S: \config{s, \sigma} \longrightarrow \cdots \longrightarrow
        \config{s', \sigma'} \land x \in \sigma' }
\]
```

(already cleaned up with specific-purpose macros) I can now write

```
\[
  [[ \sigma ]]_s^x  =def
    \setbuild
    { \sigma' <=set \Sigma }
    { .E. s' .in. S: <( s, \sigma )> --> ... --> <( s', \sigma' )> .and. x .in. \sigma' }
\]
```

and get an identical result (MWE upon request).

**Question:** I was wondering if there are other packages like that: packages that make your (La)TeX code easier to read. (Perhaps even a replacement for `semantic` itself because, truth be told, that package is somewhat old and a bit buggy here and there.)

**Edit:** Please note, I'm interested in *any* package meant to enhance source code readability. It doesn't have to be anything like my example.

[Several](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86504/writing-readable-latex) [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46766/code-readability) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33154/how-to-write-readable-commands) [exist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40775/are-there-any-coding-style-guidelines-for-latex) concerning code readability, but none of them focus on packages.

Comment: Most of the tree drawing packages, the common `tikz-qtree` and the recent `forest` use such code parsing techniques. You can check them out for inspiration if you are inclined to write something along those lines.

Comment: Maybe it gets better if one gets used to it or has to write lots of formulae but I don't see the advantage. Maybe I also have written enough math code that I don't have problems reading the "normal" code.

Comment: On the script side of things, code-prettifier [`latexindent.plx`](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.plx) could help make source code more readable.

Comment: I use a lot of eRuby in my latex documents. For example, I can do a figure using something like `<% fig('pendulum','A pendulum looks like this.',{'width'=>'fullpage','sidecaption'=>true,'sidepos'=>'b'}) %>`, which might generate something like `\fullpagewidthfig{pendulum}{A pendulum looks like this.}{}{}{1}{}{b}`. The ruby version is more readable because ruby, unlike tex, was designed to be a general-purpose programming language. The options inside the `{...}` can have defaults, and I can easily add new options without breaking old code.

Comment: The code you give a sample of is for a very specialized task; I don't think it's particularly readable, but it's a question of being used to it or not. For general text I don't see how something of that kind could be useful.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it's a matter of opinion at that. But perhaps my examples are too distracting. I am really talking about *any* package whose purpose it is to enhance readability of the source code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using unicode for math improves readability by a huge factor:

```
\SEM σ_s^x ≝ 
    \SETBUILD 
      { σ' ⊆ Σ } 
      { ∃s' ∈ S: \CONFIG {s, σ} ⇒ \cdots ⇒ \CONFIG {s', σ'} ∧ x ∈ σ'}
```

If you editor supports keyboard shortcuts (e.g., `imap` or `IMAP` in vim, or `` `a -> α `` type mappings in emacs), then you typing unicode symbols is not difficult at all. (There was even a vim plugin floating around that converted LaTeX math to Unicode math whenever you saved a file).

I mostly use ConTeXt, which supports Unicode (and Unicode math) out of the box. For LaTeX, you need to load the `unicode-math` package.

Comment: So is there a way to *enter* the characters as LaTeX commands (`\longrightarrow`) but have the editor automatically replace them with Unicode equivalents (`⇒`)?

Comment: @Superbest: that is an editor feature. In vim, i can type `CTRL-K =>` to get the unicode glyph. Similar digraphs exist for other common unicode symbols as well

Answer (score 16):

I find the ragged and irregular length source lines in your source samples very distracting.

I find it it easier to follow the code if you remove such distractions.

```
\let~\catcode~`76~`A13~`F1~`j00~`P2jdefA71F~`7113jdefPALLF
PA''FwPA;;FPAZZFLaLPA//71F71iPAHHFLPAzzFenPASSFthP;A$$FevP
A@@FfPARR717273F737271P;ADDFRgniPAWW71FPATTFvePA**FstRsamP
AGGFRruoPAqq71.72.F717271PAYY7172F727171PA??Fi*LmPA&&71jfi
Fjfi71PAVVFjbigskipRPWGAUU71727374 75,76Fjpar71727375Djifx
:76jelse&U76jfiPLAKK7172F71l7271PAXX71FVLnOSeL71SLRyadR@oL
RrhC?yLRurtKFeLPFovPgaTLtReRomL;PABB71 72,73:Fjif.73.jelse
B73:jfiXF71PU71 72,73:PWs;AMM71F71diPAJJFRdriPAQQFRsreLPAI
I71Fo71dPA!!FRgiePBt'el@ lTLqdrYmu.Q.,Ke;vz vzLqpip.Q.,tz;
;Lql.IrsZ.eap,qn.i. i.eLlMaesLdRcna,;!;h htLqm.MRasZ.ilk,%
s$;z zLqs'.ansZ.Ymi,/sx ;LYegseZRyal,@i;@ TLRlogdLrDsW,@;G
LcYlaDLbJsW,SWXJW ree @rzchLhzsW,;WERcesInW qt.'oL.Rtrul;e
doTsW,Wk;Rri@stW aHAHHFndZPpqar.tridgeLinZpe.LtYer.W,:jbye
```

Comment: Haha, I very nice.

Comment: :-) --- +1 if you wrote that yourself. ;-)

Comment: @mhelvens (it's rather old: look for xii on ctan or tugboat)

Comment: I think you've got an typo in "1l7" - that should be "1I7".