# More WYSIWYG in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I am wondering if there is some alternative to math mode or some other way to use some things directly, e.g.

```
β instead of \beta

A' instead of A^\prime

A | B instead of A \mid B (when using A | B in math mode, the space between A, | and B gets lost)
```

It would make formulas more comfortable to read.

Comment: some ideas in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96225/what-are-good-packages-techniques-for-writing-more-readable-latex-code

Answer (score 6):

It is not a good idea to change the behaviour of `|`, and `'` is by default `^\prime`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\DeclareMathSymbol{|}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"6A}
\newunicodechar{}{\alpha}
\newunicodechar{β}{\beta}

\begin{document}
\huge
$\sin()\ne\sin(β)$
$y'=y^\prime$

$A|B = A\mid B $

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1; but probably it's worth noting that the absolute value |a| can't be written with `|` any more.

Comment: but with the old definition `$\mathchar"426A a\mathchar"526A$`

Comment: Which is not very nice, is it? :) However `\mathopen|a\mathclose|` would work. In conclusion, I don't think that changing `|` to mean `\mid` is so convenient, which I think you agree to.

Comment: yes, `|` shouldn't be redefined